# Flutter login and registration not working on apk

Tags: flutter, authentication, registration, flutter-apk

**Login and Registration** aren't working on the apk that we build, but it works on the emulator, and it works when it's connected with a cable to a real phone.

Any ideas?

We haven't changed anything considering login.(controllers, service, ect.) and we are using android phones

We are also using GetX if that matters.

Is it some android permission or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might forget the **internet** permission in Android Manifest.

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add the below line inside `<manifest></manifest>`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: yeah it works great, had that permission in profile/AndroidManifest and in debug/AndroidManifest, but not in main/ AndroidManifest